# iPython Notebook svg Figures by Default

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I just started using ipython, and I'm creating figures such as:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots()
xs = range(0,100)
axes.plot(xs, [x*x for x in xs], 'r')
```

I know that the figures can be rendered as svgs, see [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/github.com/ipython/ipython-in-depth/raw/master/notebooks/Custom%20Display%20Logic.ipynb). Unfortunately, the figures are always rendered as a rasterized image. The rasterized images become very ugly when I'm using the notebook's zoom feature. Is there a way to change this behavior, such that figures are displayed as svg by default?

Comment: The link is broken; for the record, you can turn on svg rendering in the ipython notebook with the magic `%config InlineBackend.figure_formats=['svg']`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change the default figure format in the ipython profile configuration files. What I did was create a configuration profile especially for the notebook server, using:

```
ipython profile create nbserver
```

At the command line. This creates a whole bunch of files under `~/.ipython/profile_nbserver` which have example lines for almost every setting you could want to change (it might be somewhere such as `~/.config/ipython` instead depending on your OS, not sure about where it would be under windows). You need to look in the file `ipython_notebook_config.py`. You should then add the the line:

```
c.InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']
```

Note that this only applied to IPython 3.x, and that you can also specify additional formats as per @HarrySchreiner's comment. For IPython 2.x, you should set `c.InlineBackEnd.figure_format='svg'`. To use this profile you should start the notebook with

```
ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
```

If this is too much trouble then don't give a profile name when running `create`, and modify the default profile instead.

Also, you may want to have the line

```
c.IPKernelApp.matplotlib = 'inline'
```

so that each notebook will automatically start with the matplotlib inline backend used.

Originally I also wanted to use the svg backend instead of png to enable zooming etc. However, I found that certain plots, such as `pcolor` with a large number of points can just kill my browser when using the svg backend. So I find it easier to use png, and just use the `xlim` and `ylim` commands to zoom in manually if I need to.

Also, you should definitely tweak the line `c.InlineBackend.rc` to set more reasonable defaults for the figure size and the fonts used.

**edit**

Current recommended best practice is not to use `pylab`, but to explicitly import `matplotlib` and `numpy` instead, so I modified my answer to stop encouraging this. See this post for the reasons why:

http://carreau.github.io/posts/10-No-PyLab-Thanks.html

Also, if svg rendering is too slow for particular plot elements (such as `pcolor` or `plot_surface`), you can pass the option `rasterized=True` to these plot commands. This means that those particular parts of the plot will have fast pixel based rendering, but all the other plot elements will be nicely vectorized.

Comment: That now should be the line `c.InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['svg']`, and it should go in `ipython_kernel_config.py`, as of IPython 3.0.  I personally use `c.InlineBackend.figure_formats = ['pdf','png']`, as that creates both and uses the best one, for example, it uses png in the browser and pdf when you convert to pdf.

Comment: @HenrySchreiner - Thanks for the heads up. I agree the correct line is `figure_formats`, but where did you find that `ipython_kernel_config.py` is the correct file? I see no mention of `InlineBackend` at https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/options/kernel.html.

Comment: The kernel options are for things that affect the running kernel; the notebook config are for things that affect the notebook manager instance (ie, the thing that launches kernels, like the main password and notebook dir). If you look at the contents of both files, you'll see similar options (like gui interaction) in the kernel file. That option (in fact, anything relating to InlineBackend) does not show up in either of the config options by default. InlineBackend is only mentioned in IPython.kernel.zmq.pylab.config.InlineBackend in the docs.

Comment: Will this solution work with `jupyter notebook`? I thought after the recent updates, jupyter will only read from the `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. I tried adding these your `InlineBackend` line there, but the line is completely ignored.

Comment: @Luke Davis Note that IPython still exists - it is now one of many kernels for the Jupyter notebook. The `InlineBackend` settings should still be found somewhere under `.ipython`, since it is specific to that kernel. I haven't checked if all details in the post are still current. The current config options are listed at https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/kernel.html

Answer (score 27):

The magic I was looking for:

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Alternatively you might still want to show `png` but save a figure into a file:

```
plt.savefig(fig_filename, format='svg')
```